# Does this MSDN article violate MVVM?

Tags: wcf, silverlight, entity-framework, mvvm

This may be old news but back in March 2009, this article, “[Model-View-ViewModel In Silverlight 2 Apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd458800.aspx),” has a code sample that includes `DataServiceEntityBase`:

```
// COPIED FROM SILVERLIGHTCONTRIB Project for simplicity

/// <summary>
/// Base class for DataService Data Contract classes to implement 
/// base functionality that is needed like INotifyPropertyChanged.  
/// Add the base class in the partial class to add the implementation.
/// </summary>
public abstract class DataServiceEntityBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
/// <summary>
/// The handler for the registrants of the interface's event 
/// </summary>
PropertyChangedEventHandler _propertyChangedHandler;

/// <summary>
/// Allow inheritors to fire the event more simply.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="propertyName"></param>
protected void FirePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
  if (_propertyChangedHandler != null)
  {
    _propertyChangedHandler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}

#region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
/// <summary>
/// The interface used to notify changes on the entity.
/// </summary>
event PropertyChangedEventHandler INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
{
  add
  {
    _propertyChangedHandler += value;
  }
  remove
  {
    _propertyChangedHandler -= value;
  }
}
#endregion
```

What this class implies is that the developer *intends* to bind visuals *directly* to data (yes, a ViewModel is used but it defines an `ObservableCollection` of data objects). Is this design diverging too far from the guidance of MVVM? Now I can see some of the reasons Why would we go this way: what we can do with `DataServiceEntityBase` is this sort of thing (which is intimate with the Entity Framework):

```
// Partial Method to support the INotifyPropertyChanged interface
public partial class Game : DataServiceEntityBase
{
    #region Partial Method INotifyPropertyChanged Implementation
    // Override the Changed partial methods to implement the 
    // INotifyPropertyChanged interface

    // This helps with the Model implementation to be a mostly
    // DataBound implementation

    partial void OnDeveloperChanged() { base.FirePropertyChanged("Developer"); }
    partial void OnGenreChanged() { base.FirePropertyChanged("Genre"); }
    partial void OnListPriceChanged() { base.FirePropertyChanged("ListPrice"); }
    partial void OnListPriceCurrencyChanged() { base.FirePropertyChanged("ListPriceCurrency"); }
    partial void OnPlayerInfoChanged() { base.FirePropertyChanged("PlayerInfo"); }
    partial void OnProductDescriptionChanged() { base.FirePropertyChanged("ProductDescription"); }
    partial void OnProductIDChanged() { base.FirePropertyChanged("ProductID"); }
    partial void OnProductImageUrlChanged() { base.FirePropertyChanged("ProductImageUrl"); }
    partial void OnProductNameChanged() { base.FirePropertyChanged("ProductName"); }
    partial void OnProductTypeIDChanged() { base.FirePropertyChanged("ProductTypeID"); }
    partial void OnPublisherChanged() { base.FirePropertyChanged("Publisher"); }
    partial void OnRatingChanged() { base.FirePropertyChanged("Rating"); }
    partial void OnRatingUrlChanged() { base.FirePropertyChanged("RatingUrl"); }
    partial void OnReleaseDateChanged() { base.FirePropertyChanged("ReleaseDate"); }
    partial void OnSystemNameChanged() { base.FirePropertyChanged("SystemName"); }
    #endregion
}
```

Of course MSDN code can seen as “toy code” for educational purposes but is anyone doing anything like this in the *real* world of Silverlight development?

Comment: Pretty inflammatory title - any reason you're splashing someone's name and the word "violating" around in the same sentence?

Comment: Otaku: My reasoning is explicitly stated in the question body text.

Comment: No, it's not reason for targetting a person. You're specifically calling out an individual, thus potentially smearing them because of your own misunderstanding. Secondly, Shawn would have to have an editor to approve what is published, but I don't seeing you calling out MSDN for any violation or the particular editor's name. Finally, and most importantly, if you read the the article, Shawn specifically says **This example does not necessarily represent how actual code would be used. It is simply designed to explain the pattern.**. I've flagged this post as offensive.

Comment: Great work. You are protecting the innocent.

Comment: @rasx: Even though AnthonyWJones has edited your title, you seem unrepentant. I, too, am flagging offensive. Please tone down the rhetoric and ask "nice" questions. We're not here to fight.

Comment: It appears that more than one are looking for obsequious genuflection based on an unknown and unattractive cultural norm. This has historical precedent. Bring on the ironic violence. Game the system to reduce my score to zero. Why not ban me entirely from this site over writing less than three words? Just another biased standardized test of the mis-measurement of man. Grace *is* amazing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to make a View entirely independent of the Model you would need to reproduce types that in many cases are identical to the Model types in your ViewModel.

**Example**

A Model contains a `Person` type that have `FirstName` and `LastName` properties.  The visual design calls for a "List of people" so there is a View containing a ListBox that has a data template binding to property paths of `FirstName` and `LastName`.  The `ItemsSource` binds to a property of ViewModel that exposes a set instances of types that have a `FirstName` and `LastName` property.

So here is the question, **should there be a "ViewModel version" of the Model `Person` type or should the ViewModel simply re-use the existing `Person` type from the Model?**

In either case its quite possible that you would want the properties to be observable.

**To consider**

What are the objectives behind MVVM?  Quite often we like to present nice long lists of why a pattern exists but in this case there are really only 2.

- Separate visual design (**note**: not design) from code.
- Maximise the testable surface of the overall application.

Exposing Model types on the ViewModel doesn't form an obstacle to either of the above objectives.  In fact it aids testability since the number of types and members that need testing is reduced.

In my opinion I don't see that implementing INotifyPropertyChanged *implies* binding to visuals.  There may be other reasons why some service may want to observe changes in properties of a model object.

The key principle in the separation of Model from View is hiding of any specifics about the how the View presents the Model from the Model itself.  Adding a `ForenameBackColor` property to the Model would be probably be bad.  This is where the ViewModel comes in.

**Bottom Line**

Requiring the Model to expose observable properties is not breach of MVVM, its a simple and general requirement that does not require the Model to have any specific knowledge of any View or indeed that there are any "visuals" involved at all.

Comment: A very important thing for me to remember: "In my opinion I don't see that implementing INotifyPropertyChanged implies  binding to visuals. There may be other reasons why some service may want to observe changes in properties of a model object."

Answer (score 3):

No, looks fine to me - *DataServiceEntityBase* is just the name of his base class which all his DTO's/business objects inherit from, nothing wrong with that setup (did that name throw you a little?). If he is putting his data in a ViewModel and then binding his View to the VM then you at least have the VVM part of MVVM.

The main thing i would be upset about is his naming of the *FirePropertyChanged* method - personally i would have called it *On*PropertyChanged.